# Azure naming convention

Tags: azure

I’ve got a stubborn customer who wants to use the initials in front of all their resources, which is just odd. For example if the company is contoso.com they are adding cts- in front of every resource so a resource group is cts-rg-eastus-app01.

I’ve showed them the cloud adoption framework naming convention and they’re not budging, can anyone think of a  rationale for not not changing their current naming convention. This is a greenfield site and we are building all from scratch but the POC was done by a third party who chose this naming convention.

Comment: Assuming their resources are in their own resource group, does it matter that much realistically?

Comment: @JamesGould thanks that makes perfect sense, and I’m trying to suggest anything below subscription doesn’t need to have cts- in it. Can you think of a reason why you would have cats- in any of it at rg or below?

Comment: Not personally but it doesn't have much impact on development or devops I don't think - if it were me I'd just pick my battles and spend my energy on more important things. Double check that you can still find the resources easily via search, not sure if a prepend of `cts-` etc will impact that.

Comment: @JamesGould thanks and I think you’re right, but so frustrating.. time to move on I think :) thanks again.

Comment: Agreed it's frustrating but one of those things you just sigh and deal with - if anything it makes you a bit more flexible in the customer's eyes which can work in your favour down the line

Answer (score 0):

Where I have seen this naming convention used is where there is an operations company that has many clients, and they need an easy way to identify which resources belong to which client.

Comment: Thanks that would make sense, previous company is a CSP so they probably use this standard for various clients.